# SKStoreReviewController right-to-left

Tags: ios, swift, right-to-left, skstorereviewcontroller

I have set locale to Saudi Arabia and language to Arabic.
When I call `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` to show native App Store rating alert, the directions of the dismiss and cancel buttons are changed to RTL but the rating control (stars) still works in LTR.

Is it possible to make rating control work from right to left? ie. the stars get filled from right instead of left.

[image]

Comment: How did you localize this?

Comment: I wasn't able to

Comment: I’m talking about localizing the language, not the RTL.

Comment: @ataravati that is taken care of by iOS when the system language is changed to Arabic.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I was wondering if there’s a way to force the language without changing the system language.